# Access Product Option StoreView Title

Tags: magento, magento2

I need some help accessing the Magento 2 Product Option Title for a specific Storeview.

I have added the product option: "custom_code" (admin name) to a product.
For my german storeview it's called "Konfigurationscode".
For my englisch storeview it's called "Customization Code".

I have built an export script and want to access the cosen order item product options:

Some tinkering:

```
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load('44');
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$items[0]->getProductOptions();
// ... option_id" => "8",
```

From the data I have got I know that one product option has the id 8, so I fech this specific Product Option:

```
$productOption = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->load(8);
$productOption->getData();
```

unfortunately the title is not listed in the data

```
[
 "option_id" => "8",
 "product_id" => "28",
 "is_require" => "1",
 "sku" => "5",
...
]
```

How do I get the title of the order item product option? And how I got the admin name of the title and not the german or english one? I haven't found a way yet.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got a solution for me:
As suggested we should use the Repository classes:

```
$optionRepository = $objectManager-

>get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Repository');

$option = $optionRepository->get('product-sku', "8");

$option->getData();
```

Output:

```
"default_title" => "custom_code",
 "store_title" => "Konfigurationscode",
 "title" => "Konfigurationscode",
```

From the repository I can use the get() method (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ce74b2127927f21f7d1efb7b7ef9318b602ce77/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Option.php)

Note: Use the repository through dependency injection by the constructor. I used the objectManager because I ran my code inside a single script.